# Tensorflow queue closes mid-training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I get an error upon calling

```
example, label = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [example, label],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    capacity=capacity,
    min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue,
    num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
)
```

I keep getting this error and I'm not sure why it is happening:

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: RandomShuffleQueue '_4_shuffle_batch_1/random_shuffle_queue' is closed.

It seems related to the number of files that hold the training data. Until now if I used less but larger files, I wouldn't get the issue. Now I have a new batch of data and this error is happening regardless.

The full code that generates my training batches is here:

```
input_pipeline(instructions, batch_size, base_directory, num_epochs=None):
filename_list = [os.path.join(base_directory, x) for x in instructions.filename_list]
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
    filename_list, shuffle=True, capacity=100)
example, label, feature_name_list = read_binary_format(filename_queue, instructions)

num_preprocess_threads = 16
min_after_dequeue = 10000
capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size

example, label = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [example, label],
    batch_size=batch_size,
    capacity=capacity,
    min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue,
    num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
)

return tf.reshape(example, [batch_size,-1]), label
```

Any help is appreciated, I have no idea what is causing this error.